# How to handle null value in map

Tags: java, hashmap

I am facing an issue which is `NullPointerException` while printing the selected values of map. If the ***selectedCert*** list contains (`AA`,`BB`,`CC`), the map will print:

> EN
>   EN
>   EN

However, if the ***selectedCert*** list contains only 2 which are (`AA`,`BB`), there will be null pointer exception because ***ccLang*** is null.

***Snipped of code:***

```
   private String ccLang;//Setter and Getter    
   Map<String, String> Cert = new HashMap<String,String>(ss.size());

   Cert.put("AA", "EN");    
   Cert.put("BB", "EN");    
   Cert.put("CC", ccLang);   

   for(String key: selectedCert)    
      System.out.println(Cert.get(key));    
   System.out.println();
```

**How to solve this issue?**

Comment: Do null check before calling "put", is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Where is the `NullPointerException` coming from? A `HashMap` is allowed to have `null` keys and values.

Comment: Can you please verify your code? The one you posted will not compile and if "fixed" you will not get a NPE, it will just print null...

Comment: The null pointer exception is coming from the private String ccLang. The ccLang initial value is ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your value can be null, simply add a null check:

```
if(value != null) {
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

You can use a method for it:

```
private static void putNonNull(String key, String value, 
                               Map<String, String> map) {
    if(value != null) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}

putNonNull("AA", "EN", Cert);
putNonNull("BB", "EN", Cert);
putNonNull("CC", ccLang, Cert);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your way however it is still showing the null pointer exception. The ccLang variable initial value is "" (Two Quotes=Blank)

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code a bit to see if this is what you are talking about, but this will work great :

```
    String ccLang = null;//Setter and Getter

    Map<String, String> Cert = new HashMap<String,String>(10);

    Cert.put("AA", "EN");

    Cert.put("BB", "EN");

    Cert.put("CC", ccLang);

    for (Entry<String, String> entry : Cert.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
```